# What is the Hilbert space of a single photon?

Tags: hilbert-space, photons, quantum-optics, second-quantization

I'm trying to understand the second quantization of photons. Following expression (4.3.5) in the lecture note:[Second Quantization](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Quantum_Mechanics_III_(Chong)/04%3A_Identical_Particles/4.03%3A_Second_Quantization), a Hilbert space of a indistinguishable multiparticle system in second quantization is constructed by single-particle Hilbert spaces:
$$
\mathcal{H}^F_{S/A}=\mathcal{H}^{(0)}\oplus \mathcal{H}^{(1)}\oplus \mathcal{H}^{(2)}_{S/A} \oplus \mathcal{H}^{(3)}_{S/A}\oplus \dots
$$
in which $\mathcal{H}^{(1)}$ is a single-particle Hilbert space, $\mathcal{H}^{(n)}=\mathcal{H}^{(1)}\otimes \mathcal{H}^{(1)}\otimes \mathcal{H}^{(1)}\dots$ is a n-particle Hilbert space, and $\mathcal{H}^{(n)}_{S/A}$ is a symmetric/antisymmetric subspace of $\mathcal{H}^{(n)}$.
It is easy to understand when dealing with some particles, like electrons, we say that the Hilbert space of a single electron is $\mathcal{H}^{(1)}=span(\{|v_i\rangle\})$, $\{|v_i\rangle\}$ can be a complete eigenbasis set of a single-electron Hamiltonian $H$. But for a single photon, there is no such single-photon Hamiltonian, and it is hard to construct single-photon Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}^{(1)}$ from the point of single-photon Hamiltonian $H$.

So my question is, how to construct a single-photon Hilbert space(using some basis) in order to construct multiphoton system?

Comment: Why do you think there is no single-photon Hamiltonian? For example, $H=\hbar\omega a^\dagger a$ is a Hamiltonian of a single photonic mode with frequency $\omega$. It lives in the single-particle Hilbert-space $\mathcal{H}^{(1)}$.

Comment: @RudolfSmorka, even though the Hamiltonian you show is for a single mode, it's still a second quantized one, that allows for different occupation numbers, meaning the Hilbert space is not a single particle one, no? The ground state is vacuum, for example, and the excitations correspond to n photons.

Comment: Well, the occupation (quantum) number $n$ in the single-particle Fock space of the HO does not really tell there are $n$ bosons in the system. It rather means that the $n+1$th eigenstate of the HO is occupied. Consider 2 bosons, the Hilbert space is $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}^{(1)}\otimes \mathcal{H}^{(2)}$, and a possible state (up to normaliz. and symmetr.) would look like $\vert n_1 n_2\rangle$, where $n_1$ and $n_2$ denote the occupation number for bosons "1" and "2". BE-statistics tells us they can occupy the same state, but still, this state lives in the composite 2-particle Fock space.

Comment: @Rudolf Smorka, the Hamiltonian you provided here is a single photonic MODE Hamiltonian, rather than a single-photon Hamiltonian. According to your point of view, a multimode multiphoton system is built by many single mode Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}^0 \oplus \mathcal{H}^1 \oplus \mathcal{H}^2 \oplus ...$, in which $\mathcal{H}^n$ is a tensor product of $\mathcal{H}^1$ for n times, and $\mathcal{H}^1$ is a Hilbert space with eigenbasis composed of different occupation states, the number of photons is just a label of the state of oscillator.

Comment: In other words, a mode or an oscillator corresponds to an electron, while occupation states of a oscillator corresponds to a single electron states, like momentum eigenstates. But I want to know that if I treat each photon as a particle, say an electron, what its single-particle Hilbert space should looks like?

Comment: So you are thinking of single bosonic particle, *and*, on top of that the occupation number should be fixed to $n=1$? I am understanding correctly?

Comment: After having a closer look at the reference you gave, I see a possible misunderstanding, mainly because of confusing notation (for example see 4.3.1 and 4.3.2). When you mean single photon, do you mean states like $\vert 1,0,0\dots\rangle,\vert 0,1,0,\dots\rangle$? In this case there is an exact map to the space of spinless noninteracting fermions. And, in principle, you can avoid taking Kronecker products, and simply represent these states by the canonical cartesian unit vectors.

Comment: @Rudolf Smorka, "When you mean single photon, do you mean states like |1,0,0…⟩,|0,1,0,…⟩?"  >>>>>>>>Yes, single photon states I refer is the lowest excited state of an oscillator.  
"And, in principle, you can avoid taking Kronecker products, and simply represent these states by the canonical cartesian unit vectors."  >>>>>>>>Do you mean that I can represent a multiphoton state as a high-level excited state of a harmonic oscillator, instead of tensor product of many single-photon states?

Comment: To answer your question, I first have to understand what you mean by "multiphoton state" and "high-level excited state". What I mean is this: Take $\vert 1,0,0,\dots \rangle$ for example. This is just short-hand notation for $\vert 1\rangle \otimes \vert 0\rangle \otimes \vert 0\rangle\otimes  \dots \in \mathcal{H}^{(1)}\otimes \mathcal{H}^{(2)} \otimes \mathcal{H}^{(3)}\otimes \dots $. The system is a collection of harmonic oscillators, and if the system is in this state, then all but one oscillator are in their GS and the one which isn't, is in the 1. excited state.

Comment: @Rudolf Smorka, "multiphoton state" and "high-level excited state" is the same in my words. EM field is composed of many modes, each mode is a harmonic oscillator, and the energy level of a harmonic oscillator correspends to the number of photons in this mode. So "multiphoton state" or "high-level excited state" refers to the states like |3,0,0...> representing 3 photons are in the first mode while other modes are vaccum state, and |1,0,1,...> represents one photon in the first and another one in the third mode.

Comment: Ok, got it. Then the single-photon states you were asking for are living in the tensor product space $\mathcal{H}=\bigotimes_i \mathcal{H}^{(i)}$ where $\mathcal{H}^{(i)}$ are the truncated, two-dimensional, bosonic single-particle spaces, under the constraint that the total number of particles is 1. However, it is not clear to me why you want to build a single-photon space first, to construct the multi-photon one from it, instead of constructing the basis vectors of the multi-photon space from the beginning.

Comment: @Rudolf Smorka, I just want to make an analogy of photons with electrons, which is more familiar for me, in the sense of their mathmatical structure. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes I see that. And as I mentioned before, for the special case you have in mind there exists a mapping between the harmonic oscillator and the single-particle fermionic problem. If you're interested, more details can be found in this paper http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~batista/classes/v572/StockThoss.pdf (p. 67, B. $N$-level system)